# In Pushing Daisies Digby has lived much longer than a normal dog since he's been "alive again"; is he immortal? Therefore is Chuck immortal?

Tags: character, pushing-daisies

I know they can still die but if nothing happened to them will they not age and remain alive?

Comment: Never seen series, so dont know. But normally if he is brought back he is mortal. Any hint series where he is immortal.

Comment: I've seen all episodes, but it's been a while. I *can't remember* if anyone squarely addressed the subject of "after the Piemaker brings you back from the dead, can you still die of old age in the natural way?"

Comment: Digby should be 23, old for a dog but he doesn't seem elderly or aged at all. I don't recall it being addressed either.

Comment: It strikes me that there's a fighting chance that Ned himself *didn't know* the answer to this question. If memory serves: Until the time of the main action of the series, he'd never raised any humans from the dead who stayed alive very long afterwards. By the end of the series, it's probably only been what, a year or two since he raised Chuck? So the only way to be sure would be to wait **decades** for her, or some other human test case, to either visibly grow older and eventually keel over from a heart attack and die again . . . or else see that they were not getting visibly older at all!

Comment: Note: Yes, Digby was still going strong at a rather old age for a dog, but the rules for dogs and the rules for humans may be different. (The way Ned could restore dead, rotten fruit to *perfect condition* with his touch was different from the way humans tended to still have the *visible effects* of their fatal injuries after he had touched their corpses, so who knows if dogs and humans also get different benefits from his power?)